# Animate Circle Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I am trying to animate a moving circle from one location to another. In the example below, it is from (10, 10) to (50, 50) Below is the code for my Bullet class. When the user clicks space, I create a new Bullet object and I am trying to animate it. How do I create a smooth animation?

```
class Bullet{
    
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = 10;
    }

    draw(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill();
    }
    fire(locationX, locationY){
        
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.key == ' '){
            var currBullet = new Bullet(10, 10);
            currBullet.fire(50, 50);
        }
});

function reset(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the bullets. What is the overall goal of this? Are you planning on shooting bullets from (10, 10) to (50, 50)? Does the distance traveled need to be limited? Or will be be shooting it in a direction based on where the player is facing? Do you want to limit the number of bullets?

This code does what you asked but is very limited.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

let bullets = [];

class Bullet{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = 10;
    }

    draw(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update(){
        this.x += 1
        this.y += 1
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.code === 'Space'){
            fire()      
        }
});

function fire() {
    bullets.push(new Bullet(10, 10))
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i=0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    bullets[i].draw()
    bullets[i].update()
    if (bullets[i].x >= 50 && bullets[i].y >= 50) {
      bullets.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, I am planning to shoot bullets from one coord to another. I will probably limit the distance and have the direction be towards the mouse position. I tried running your code snippet, but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you press SPACE? works fine for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad I forgot to. Thanks for the help, it works.

Comment: Here is a more advanced example. Using mouse to shoot https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/oNWrmwy